# reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application

Tags: javascript, cordova, phonegap-build, recaptcha

I am trying to integrate google recaptcha with cordova html5 application. But cordova uses file protocol in the application. So using captcha in the app gives **"Error: invalid domain for site key"**.

I am using cordova 3.5.0 for building the application and `<access origin="*" />` is added in config.xml.

Is recaptcha can be used only for web applications and not for hybrid/native aapplications?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

reCaptcha cannot be used directly in a cordova project because of protocol issues. Either

-we have to load reCaptcha url in a separate **webview**

-Use **secure token** way of loading reCaptcha that they introduced recently (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/secure_token)

Comment: Is this answer outdated now?
Seems with removing the domain name validation we can use reCaptcha in Cordova projects.

Comment: @theunexpected1 Have you tested removing domain name validation? It didn't make any difference for me!

Comment: @AlirezaMirian, likewise, it did not work for me. It may have been a possibility earlier, but now it simply did not work. In my use-case I went for relying on redirecting to Mobile Browser in case of a captcha scenario. Hope that helps.

Comment: Use of secure tokens is not advised as this is now a depricated feature.

Answer (score 8):

I successfully made it working by using [`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview`](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview)

*Note that my project was not a Ionic project, so any cordova project can use it*

What I did :

- Configure [Re-Captcha admin console](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin/) to allow `myapp.local` domain
- Configure [`cordova-plugin-ionic-webview` preferences](https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview#configuration) :

  - Add a `<preference name="Hostname" value="myapp.local" />` in `config.xml` file
  - Add a `<allow-navigation href="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/*" />` in `config.xml` file
  - Add a `<allow-navigation href="http://myapp.local/*" />` in android's specific section in `config.xml` file
- Install ionic webview plugin : `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@4.1.3`
- Add recaptcha (v3 in my case) to your `index.html` file : `<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=MY_RECAPTCHA_KEY_HERE"></script>`
- Call recaptcha API in your JS code :

  ```
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
    grecaptcha.execute("MY_RECAPTCHA_KEY_HERE", {action: 'my-page'}).then(function(token) {
      console.log("Acquired recaptcha token : ", token);
    }, function() {
      console.error("ReCaptcha token acquisition failed", arguments);
    });
  });
  ```

Comment: This should be the accepted as the answer

Answer (score 2):

You should now use your App package name (November 2017). As part of your reCaptcha configuration you specify the domains or mobile package names that will use the service.  If you use "localhost" for development, you must add it to the list of domains.

For mobile users, the API key pair is only unique to the specified package names (for example, com.google.recaptcha.test).

However, if your domain or package name list is extremely long, fluid, or unknown, you have the option to turn off the domain or package name checking on reCAPTCHA's end, and instead check on your server.

Use of *secure tokens* is *not advised* as this is now a *depricated feature*.

#### Reference:

- [Domain/Package Name Validation](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/domain_validation)

Comment: Do you mean you can use the regular recaptcha V2 for mobile sites by simply adding the Android app package name to the list of allowed domains?