# Is there a way to use Google Recaptcha in a Phonegap app?

Tags: cordova, captcha, recaptcha, simplecaptcha

I can't find an answer to that question, secure token is an option but how can I use it with javascript only?

In my recaptcha app configuration I have localhost as domain, what should I put there when I want to display it in a Phonegap app?

Comment: Umm... and what's the purpose of having captcha in installable application?

Comment: I dont know, do you think is not necessary?

Comment: @c-smile well, then existence of tools like [this one](http://dustingram.com/articles/2010/06/18/automated-control-of-an-android-device-with-python/) makes it very possible to control an app using scripting, so captcha could be a solution...?

Comment: @dieg8 captcha is needed if that page is sitting on server. If that page is part of your application and only your application can open it then captcha is not needed. I don't think we have robots capable to go to appstore and install application automatically. And yet to inject their code into your app on the device to send data ...

Comment: All the HTML and JS files are part of the Phonegap application. The problem is that the forms inside the app are sent to a WebService. What if they use a bot to simulate clicks on the "Send Form" button?

Comment: As a workaround its possible to use inAppBrowser to display captcha.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application)