# Using reCAPTCHA with phonegap

Tags: cordova, recaptcha

I'm using reCAPTCHA within a phonegap app when registering a user.  This returns the error:

"ERROR for site owner: invalid domain for site key"

Now I know this is because Google is trying to verify that the domain serving up the captcha, is the same as the one that the keys are registered to.  Obviously phonegap doesn't have a domain name, hence the error.

However, I've unticked the "Verify the origin of reCAPTCHA solutions" box in the domain name validation advanced options of the Google reCAPTCHA admin and it still says the same thing.

Google say "If disabled, you are required to check the hostname on your server when verifying a solution."

I'm not sure what is meant by that though.  I'm getting the error before the captcha is even displayed.

Comment: did you find any solution?

Comment: The docs regarding host name validation seem to be specific to backend implementations: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify.

Comment: Any update or solution?

Comment: As a workaround its possible to use inAppBrowser to display captcha.

Comment: I have the same problem too. Any update about this? It works fine in browser, but not working in cordova mobile app.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application)