# recaptcha integration with ionic hybrid app

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, recaptcha

I have read many post related to integrate google recaptcha with ionic hybrid app,
I didn't found any solution for it.
I have some following question regarding g-recptcha use in ionic app:

1) Can I used google recaptcha with ionic app?
2) if I used recaptcha then what is my domain name in 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin' ?

I tried it with domain name 'localhost' it is work on browser but not on mobile
giving error in mobile is'error for site owner:invalid domain for site key'

Comment: Check your app http request. it contain admin-pc/signup or other  name 'xyz. com/signup'  and get site key of  these particular  domain names.

Comment: @pandian_Snkl When an ionic app runs in a mobile device, it runs with a file URL. so I think it would not have domain names. is there any other solution to this?

Comment: did you find any solution for this problem?

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116411/recaptcha-ionic-cordova-on-android/

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application)

Answer (score -1):

You can register a new reCAPTCHA for cordova/ionic app, and just add your app package name in it.

Then choose "reCAPTCHA Android".

Use new public key (site key) in cordova/ionic.

It will work!

Comment: What about iOS?

Comment: I did not test it in iOS, maybe you can do it like android

Comment: did you test this solution? I've tried it in android but it did not work.

Comment: @amos Hey! I've been trying to do that all day, without any success. Is it not working anymore? Can you post a code sample please? I get the same error even thought i created the key for android, whitelisted the package name, it still doesnt work.