# reCaptcha v2 & Invisible Captcha on Cordova-based apps

Tags: android, ios, cordova, recaptcha, captcha

Has anyone ever tried to integrate reCaptcha v2 or the invisible captcha on a Cordova-based app?
I have configured everything correctly. Once I launch my page as a Web Site, everything works great and I see the reCaptcha v2 working. However, when I run the page as an app on Android or iOS I see the error which says:

> ERROR for site owner:
>   Invalid domain for site key

I've also unchecked the option in Google Console to prevent the domain check, but it only affected the web site and not the app.

Does anyone have any experience integrating reCaptcha v2 or invisilbe Captcha in a cordova-based app?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deep investigation seems that the issue is related to the fact that the Cordova-based apps run over the file:/// protocol which seems to cause the issue.
Actually we've faced the issue only on Android devices, ios devices seem to work fine.
We've finally fixed the issue creating a web page on our web site and putting there the invisible recaptcha library then we've linked the page inside an iFrame in the app.
This tricks let us to run the recaptcha library over the http protocol which has fixed the issue.

Comment: But then how do you call the recaptcha API that you loaded to the iframe without triggering "same-origin" problems?

Answer (score 0):

Try to install cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest using the below command

```
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-ionic-webview@latest
```