# recaptcha integration with ionic app

Tags: cordova, ionic2, recaptcha

I have read many post related to integrate google recaptcha with ionic hybrid app, I didn't find any solution for it. I have the following questions regarding g-recaptcha use in ionic app:

1. Can I used google recaptcha with ionic app?
2. if I used recaptcha then what is my domain name in 'https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin'?

I tried it with domain name 'localhost' and it works in browser but not on mobile. The error in mobile is 'error for site owner:invalid domain for site key'.

Then I tried registering a new reCAPTCHA for cordova/ionic app, and just added my app package name in it.
Then I chose "reCAPTCHA Android" and used a new public key (site key) in cordova/ionic but it is also giving the same error while testing in phone. Any solutions?

Comment: I have the exact same problem. Tried everything, but nothing seem to work. I've tried to use "recaptcha v2" keys, and "recaptcha android" and "recaptcha invisible" keys too. 
Enabled and disabled domain check in https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin.
Enabled domain check and used 'localhost' and '127.0.0.1' in domain list.
Nothing, it didn't work.
I would like if we can try to resolve our problem discussing about it. Have you any idea of what can we try to fix it?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Hi @MarkO'Brian , thanks for replying but i also don't know how to fix. for me the captcha is working fine in browser but not in mobile. I am not able to find any solution for this.other than this, I want to ask if you know how to implement text captcha in ionic app with or without using google api.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know how to implement text captcha. 
Unfortunately for me is mandatory to implement google v2 recaptcha, as v1 recaptcha is going to be shutted off in march, 31 2018. So i have no other choices.

Comment: is recaptcha working fine for you in browser ?

Comment: yes, working fine in my browser but not inside the enviroment of my cordova mobile app.

Comment: Have you tried this :                                                                              You can register a new reCAPTCHA for cordova/ionic app, and just add your app package name in it.

Then choose "reCAPTCHA Android".
you are testing it by building apk or in android studio?
Use new public key (site key) in cordova/ionic.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that too but with no luck.
I'm testing it by building apk.

Comment: I've checked the POST request fired when the recaptcha is rendered inside the page of the app. 
There are some differences from the POST request sent from the browser, and the one sent from the app.
The header of the POST request sended from the app, is missing the 'referer' field, and this could be the problem. 
But I don't know how to force this parameter inside the header, because the request is managed directly by the "recaptcha javascript file" downloaded directly from google: https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js

Comment: i don't know which 'referer' feild you are talking about. i am using [link] (https://www.joshmorony.com/adding-captcha-to-ionic-with-nodejs-middleware/)

Comment: any updates? did you find any way ?

Comment: Hi, I ended up making a plugin for this purpose, as we couldn't get it working, and it was needed. Check it out and cehck if its what you need https://github.com/nombrekeff/ionic-recaptcha-plugin-android

Comment: Maybe this might help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49116411/recaptcha-ionic-cordova-on-android/

Comment: @Keff I ran into the same issue, how did you manage with iOS version captcha work?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late reply. I couldn't figure out how to make it work on iOS... plugin did not work, as it uses native android libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [reCaptcha usage in cordova/phonegap application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application)

Answer (score 1):

Almost 5 years later but this is the to-go solution.
Warning: You may broke some apis that expect the hostname to be localhost on Android / iOs.

The problem: A mobile app hostname on runtime is "localhost". When using ionic it may be different hostname for each platform.

The solution:

With cordova: (idk why would you be using cordova in 2023..) check [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32611205/recaptcha-usage-in-cordova-phonegap-application) from @FrédéricCamblor

With capacitor:

1. Go to https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin and register a custom domain under your site allowed domains.
2. [Initialize capacitor](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/plugins/cordova) in your project (with CLI) if you haven't already.
3. Add the following configurations to capactor.config.json

> ```
> "server": {
>   "hostname": "yourapp.example.local",
>   "allowNavigation":["https://www.google.com/recaptcha/",
> "http://yourapp.example.local/*"]
> }
> ```

You can check the full [capacitor config schema](https://capacitorjs.com/docs/config)

4. As an extra step i added the `@awesome-cordova-plugins/ionic-webview wrapper` although idk if is requiered whatsoever, that is how i made it work.